# BetterCMS Security options

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bettercms

Hi I've basically started a new build with BetterCMS, but theres an issue, within the cms.config ive added the following code:

```
<security accessControlEnabled="true" fullAccessRoles="Owner" encryptionEnabled="false" encryptionKey="bettercmstest">
  <defaultAccessRules defaultAccessLevel="ReadWrite">
    <add identity="Everyone" accessLevel="Read" isRole="true" />
    <add identity="Authenticated Users" accessLevel="Read" isRole="true" />
  </defaultAccessRules>
</security>
```

Now this should all the identity="Everyone" to have a default access level set to read. However when ever I create a new page or blog it is set to no Access. Has anyone had this sort of issue before and if so is there something I'm missing out. Here is the site documentation: https://github.com/devbridge/BetterCMS/wiki/CMS-configuration#security-configuration

Comment: I don't know anything about bettercms... but your config says the default access level is ReadWrite... but all your users only have Read access

Answer (score 1):

So your code basically looks good, but with bettercms you will be inheriting the properties from the master class for the news or blog pages. So if the news or blog pages, Masterpage is set to "No access" then news or blog page will inherit this property.